# AS3: Air For Android - Using hardware back key to navigate to last used scene

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I have been searching around to find a generic way to use the back key on android devices to go back to the previous scene you were on. All I seem to find is how to make it so the button does not close the application.

Here is my current code:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown, false, 0, true)

function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
  if( event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK )
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //handle the button press here.

  }
}
```

Comment: add it when button click event occurs super.onBackPressed();

Comment: onBackPressed() will help you

Comment: Can anyone show me how this would look in my code please? I'm having difficulty with the logic.

Comment: @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
           super.onBackPressed();
    }

Comment: SO its been mentioned in comments, but I'll flesh this out-  the back key on android doesn't send a keyevent.  Its captured by the system and makes a special call in the Java framework-  onBackPressed.  If your javascript framework allows it to be captured, you should see a special call somewhere to do that.  If not, I would assume that whoever wrote your framework either didn't know about it or didn't think it was important to catch.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it on my Android device, just change trace() with your function:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPressed);  

private function onKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK)
    {
         event.preventDefault();
         //Now you can call your function.
         trace("Hello World");
    }
}
```